# Why my system hangs with ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: hard-drive

My system hangs when i am using the inkspace in my ubuntu 20.04. this is a repeated issue where i cant find any trace in the logs

Comment: You might find the answer in the Inkspace community. I had a problem with RapidMiner software. It would hang while starting then I went searching for Rapidminer community and there I found the solution. Here's the [Inkspace Community](https://inkscape.org/community/) and their [chat room](https://chat.inkscape.org/channel/inkscape_user) Take a look at the Ask Smart Question pdf in community page.

Answer (score 1):

Image editing applications frequently hang when they run out of memory. Inkscape uses your computer's RAM, and if your computer has a discrete graphics card which has its own RAM it also uses that memory. If there is a hardware fault in either type of RAM it can cause Inkscape to hang. What happens if you save your work more frequently in Inkscape in order to free up memory? If Inkscape has been running out of memory this will prevent your system from hanging.

You can replicate this situation experimentally with a notekeeping app like Gnote. Create 40 notes in Gnote, wrtite something in each note and save it, select all 40 notes, right-click and select *Open in New Window*. The Gnote windows will spread out over your desktop like playing cards in solitaire, and the system will hang for a while and then it will stop hanging.

Another possibility is that there is a bug in Inkscape. There are two versions of Inkscape in the Software app and both are named inkscape, the apt package and the snap package. If there is a bug in one version and you install the other version then maybe your system will stop hanging.